# ReCaptcha domain locks, why is it considered a security risk?

Tags: security, captcha, recaptcha

From this page I have found a way to disable the domain lock for the Google reCaptcha: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation

It says this is a security risk but it does not give any concrete examples how. What does it matter if someone else is able to use the same captcha (and I doubt they could to begin with, the backend has a secret that you need for the authentication procedure).

Can someone explain this to me?